# Best way to achieve private functions in lua object?

Tags: oop, lua, privacy

I'm learnig Lua and how OOP in Lua works and I've seen this code in the [reference](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.4.html)

```lua
  function newAccount (initialBalance)
      local self = {balance = initialBalance}
    
      local withdraw = function (v)
                         self.balance = self.balance - v
                       end
    
      local deposit = function (v)
                        self.balance = self.balance + v
                      end
    
      local extra = function ()
        if self.balance > self.LIM then
          return self.balance*0.10
        else
          return 0
        end
      end

      local getBalance = function () return self.balance + self.extra() end

      return {
        withdraw = withdraw,
        deposit = deposit,
        getBalance = getBalance
      }
    end
```

This seems to work fine but when I print the address of a the private function before the return like this

```lua
...
print(extra)      
return {
        withdraw = withdraw,
        deposit = deposit,
        getBalance = getBalance
      }
```

and then create two accounts

```lua
account1 = newAccount(1)
account2 = newAccount(1)
```

I get two different address values

```
function: 00D2B290
function: 00A22040
```

Is this OK? I understand this as the same function being instanciated once per object constructor, wouldn't be more efficient if the same function was instanciated once and then refencenced? Or is this something lua handles this way?(I've been coding in C++ recently where this could be a problem I guess)

I know that I could make this

```lua
local function private_extra(self)
    if self.balance > self.LIM then
        return self.balance*0.10
    else
        return 0
    end
end

local function newAccount (initialBalance)
    local self = {balance = initialBalance}

    local withdraw = function (v)
        self.balance = self.balance - v
    end

    local deposit = function (v)
        self.balance = self.balance + v
    end

    local getBalance = function () return self.balance + private_extra(self) end

    return {
        withdraw = withdraw,
        deposit = deposit,
        getBalance = getBalance,
    }
end
```

and it could work the same way and the address of the function would be the same when the constructor is called more than once. Would this be a better approach talking about efficiency? Although I think that it makes the code uglier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, a function object must refer to both the closure environment and the function's code. In your example, the two `extra` functions have different addresses, because they are two different closures. In other words, each one refers to a different `self` variable. However, they do both refer to the same function code, so there shouldn't be a significant impact on performance.

I'm not even sure why PiL uses a `self` variable in `newAccount`, since it returns a whole different table. Private data can all be stored in local variables, and anything you want public can be in the returned table.

Comment: so even if the function address is different, they do both refer to the same function address?

Comment: @edugomez102 no - even though the addresses are different, they refer to the same *function*. Lua has [*closures*](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html): Functions are *closed* with a set of *upvalues*. These local variables are what can be used to implement "private" variables.